# Keep the first rows of continuous specific values in a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
df
col1    col2
 1       A
 2       A
 3       A
 4       A
 5       A
 6       A
 7       B
 8       B
 9       A
 10      A
 11      A
 12      A
 13      B
 14      A
 15      B
 16      A
 17      A
 18      A
```

Now if there is continuous B or only one row between two Bs then display starting rows of those Bs.

So final output would look like,

```
 col1    col2
 7       B
 13      B
```

I could do this using a for loop by comparing the row values, but the execution time will be huge. I am looking for any pandas shortcut or any other method to do it most efficiently.

Comment: Why `15      B` is not in output?

Comment: @jezrael because the is one A between two Bs considering the A is the part of B, (the number of A can be changed dynamically)

Comment: So in another words last `B` is removed, because no another `B` to end? And if `16      B` then also is added to output `15 B`, becaus elast group has 2 values of B?

Comment: @jezrael The last groups starts with 13-B and ends with 15-B. Only starting row is what I am looking for.

Comment: check the solution that I've uploaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first replace non `B` values to missing values and then forward filling them by limit `1` - so last 2 `B` create one group and last get first values of `B` groups:

```
m = df['col2'].where(df['col2'].eq('B')).ffill(limit=1).eq('B')
df = df[ m.ne(m.shift()) & m]
print (df)
    col1 col2
6      7    B
12    13    B
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use shift and vector logic:

```
a = df['col2']
mask = (a.shift(1) != a) & ((a.shift(-1) == a) | (a.shift(-2) == a)) & (a == 'B')
df = df[mask]
```

Comment: Ah, why 13 should be included? I understood that the group of B's is accepted if it's of  >1 element, I'm sorry. I'll prepare a correction...

Comment: Corrected, check it now. What should it produce in case "B B B A B" or "B B B A B A B"? just one B?

Comment: BBBBB and the row with first B in this group should be considered

Answer (score 0):

```
cols = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    if i!=0:
        if df['col2'][i]==B and df['col2'][i-1]!=B:
            if i>=2 and df['col2'][i-1]!=B:
                cols.append(df['col1'][i])

print(df[df['col1'].isin(cols)])
```

Output:

```
col1    col2
 7       B
 13      B
```

find indexes with B not having it's i-1 and i-2 row not having B and retrieve the rows from data frames of retrieved indexes.